# Create a Telephone Directory like listing in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, data-binding, oracle10g

I have some Contact data in a table in following way.

```
Contact_Name              Contact Details

Acting Generals Office      ABCD
BlackBerryOffice                A1B1
BBM Help                        X1Y1
Customer Care               A2B2
D_Link Routers              A3B3
```

Now in a page I have to show the data in this fashion in my **ASP.NET page** - (First Character of each entry and under that all the entries with that character)

### A

Acting Generals Office

### B

BlackBerryOffice
BBM Help

### C

Customer Care

### D

D_Link Routers

Please refer to the below image for more details.
[image]

Clicking on Acting Generals Office,BlackBerryOffice,Customer Care,D_Link Routers will redirect to a new page where it will display the respective contact_details. (by clicking Acting Generals Office following will openup)

```
Acting Generals Office      ABCD
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: what do you mean respective contact_details? how ABCD or A1B2 should be displayed?

Comment: Yes,If I click to Acting Generals Office then below will display

Acting Generals Office      ABCD

Comment: @Izikon Can you please help me to achieve the Telephone Directory like listing, I think the rest I can manage.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide sample output that you want to get? Because it's hard to tell what you really need by looking at your question. For now, try this and provide feedback if it is what you are looking for:

```sql
CREATE TABLE contacts (
  contact_name VARCHAR2(40),
  contact_details VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO contacts VALUES ('Acting Generals Office', 'ABCD');
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES ('BlackBerryOffice', 'A1B1');
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES ('Customer Care', 'A2B2');
INSERT INTO contacts VALUES ('D_Link Routers', 'A3B3');

COMMIT;

-- show all letters, even when there are no contacts belonging to any of them
WITH letters AS (
  SELECT CHR(65 + level - 1) AS letter
    FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= ASCII('Z') - ASCII('A') + 1
)
SELECT lt.letter, ct.contact_name
  FROM letters lt
    LEFT JOIN contacts ct ON (lt.letter = UPPER(SUBSTR(ct.contact_name, 1, 1)))
ORDER BY 1, 2
;

Output:

LETTER CONTACT_NAME                           
------ ----------------------------------------
A      Acting Generals Office                   
B      BlackBerryOffice                         
C      Customer Care                            
D      D_Link Routers                           
E                                               
F                                               
.
.
.
Z           

-- Output only those letters where there are associated contacts

SELECT SUBSTR(contact_name, 1, 1), contact_name
  FROM contacts
ORDER BY 1, 2
;

Output:

SUBSTR(CONTACT_NAME,1,1) CONTACT_NAME                           
------------------------ ----------------------------------------
A                        Acting Generals Office                   
B                        BlackBerryOffice                         
C                        Customer Care                            
D                        D_Link Routers
```

Try at on SQLFiddle: <kbd>[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70726/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much for your help actually I want to display it in a ASP.NET page. I am editing the question in a better way to elucidate it. Let me know if you need anymore details.

Comment: @Subhamoy Is your question about C# or Oracle? What do you really need? C# code? What have you tried so far and why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: I need the C# Code. I tried at first to show with an GridView or DataList of ASP.NET but I am unable to achieve the Dictionary/Directory like listing.